# Creating a very large scrollable (by holding a right mouse button down) Canvas with Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have been struggling with this for a very, very long time (6 months plus).  There have been some partial answers to my question but I have been unable to put the available asnswer-bits together to be able to do anything useful with it.  This code will be an amazing tool for all new aspiring simple canvas game developers and will greatly benefit the community for sure.

-I need to create a very large scrollable canvas (scrolled by holding right mouse button), similar to this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator , say 50k px by 50k px and this (size)should be amendable in code.

-When we scroll, the background moves and all items, of course, will need to move with this  scroll.

-There have to be some measure of scroll rate in code, which is should be amendable.

-Rendering structure need to remain as in my codepen - simple constructor objects generated on screen then rendered using request animation frame.  https://codepen.io/alexhermanuk/pen/bGGXLZG

```
var squares = [];

var Square = function(x,y,w,h,color){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.w = w;
this.h = h;
this.color = color;


}

Square.prototype.update = function(){
this.draw();

}

Square.prototype.draw = function(){

context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = this.color;
context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h)
context.closePath();
context.restore();

}

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
squares.push(new Square(width*Math.random(),height*Math.random(),100,100,"red"));
}


function animateEverything(){

    context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        context.save()
            squares.forEach(Square => {Square.update(squares)})
                requestAnimationFrame(animateEverything);

}

animateEverything();

}
```

-Canvas / scrollable area need to be full screen without overflows

-Canvas background will consist of 4 virtually identical square images (2 main images and 2 mirror images) and these images are rendered/ replicated as a background as we scroll left right up or down and will create an unlimited background image (in our case it is just a wavy ocean).  So, these have to be logically rendered like a tile map of some sort...  There is no easy way to provide sample images, so please, bring yours along.

I appreciate YOUR effort and thank all in advance.

Comment: Can you provide what exactly you want to draw on big size canvas ??. Because the canvas size in given link is small or screen size you can say. It is just some thing that you need to maintain the object position canvas and update it according to scrolling.

Comment: I would like to draw, say, squares as per constructor above, with, say, coordinates 20,000 for X and 30,000 for Y then be able to scroll to them while right mouse button is held.  My canvas is the width of the screen but in effect, when we scroll, i want it to be 100k px or so.. or whichever we indicate.   Eventually, of course, the squares will be replaced with game items, images/sprites etc.

Comment: ok then you need to put all drawable element's position in an array and when you scroll canvas just update the position of element according to scroll

Comment: Scrolling is part of the problem and I do understand what is required in principle.  The second issue is logical generation of background as we scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. It scrolls with 'right click' drag.

I wasn't sure what you meant by scroll rate. Do you want the scroll rate displayed, or controlled? Anyways, I did both to be safe. `scrollRate` controls have fast it scrolls, and it defaults to 1. `scrollMeter` is a number that loosely represents how fast the canvas is being scrolled. It is printed in the top left corner of the canvas.

And about tiling, I made a BackgoundTile class. You can create 4 different tiles with different `x, y`, and `x_gap, y_gap` to have what you want. But if you care about performance, instead of making 4 tile objects, use just one with a combined image. Use an image editor to combine the 4 squares to make one big square if possible. Tiling is almost always a performance heavy job, and a bit of optimization goes a long way.

I also added a window/canvas resize handler, so the aspect ratio doesn't go haywire. This also prevents the canvas from going low-res when you enlarge the window/canvas.

I left `animateEverything` as is, but I'd recommend adding more control to rendering instead of recursively calling it indefinitely.

I hope you like this demo.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/kennygomdori/pen/yLybPBr)

Comment: Hello. The demo is great, i'd prefer scroll / drag in the direction of the drag.  otherwise we drag right and canvas moves left.  I will attempt to test it on what I have here...

Comment: I fixed it. You can also change the direction of the drag by setting `scrollRate` to a negative number.

Comment: Changing scroll rate to a neg number works very nicely and changing the scrollRate also works very nicely, as intended.  you advised you have fixed something in codePen OR you just changed the scrollRate to negative? Now i will put my best graphic designer hat on and try create one background image, as per your advice, with mirror edges, so there  are no gaps when the images are rendered.  I am yet to explore the effect on clientX and clientY / general coordinate system when i identify objects by clicking on them.

Answer (score 1):

paste below on in this link https://codepen.io/alexhermanuk/pen/bGGXLZG.

I have added vertical scroll only

you can implement horizontal in same way.

```
window.onload = function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
maxWidth = 15000,
maxHeight = 15000;


var origin = { x: 0, y: 0},
scrollY = 0,
isMouseDownOn = '',
scrollBarWidth = 25,
scrollThumbHeight = 45,
navButtonSize = 25,
totalScrollHeight = height-navButtonSize*2-scrollThumbHeight;


canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
window.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

var squares = [];

var Square = function(x,y,w,h,color){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.w = w;
this.h = h;
this.color = color;
}

Square.prototype.update = function(){
this.draw();
}
Square.prototype.draw = function(){
var newY = this.y - origin.y;
context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = this.color;
context.fillRect(this.x,newY,this.w,this.h)
context.closePath();
context.restore();

}

for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
squares.push(new Square(width*Math.random(),maxHeight*Math.random(),100,100,"red"));
}


function animateEverything(){
context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
context.save()
console.log(' m here')
squares.forEach(Square => {
Square.update(squares)
})
drawScrollbar();
drawOrigin ();
//requestAnimationFrame(animateEverything);
}
animateEverything();










function drawScrollbar() {
var currentScroll = scrollY+navButtonSize;
context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fillRect((width-navButtonSize ),0,navButtonSize,navButtonSize);
context.closePath();
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fillRect((width-navButtonSize ),(navButtonSize),scrollBarWidth,(height-navButtonSize*2));
context.closePath();
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fillRect((width-navButtonSize ),(height-navButtonSize),navButtonSize,navButtonSize);
context.closePath();

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fillRect((width-navButtonSize),currentScroll,scrollBarWidth,scrollThumbHeight);
context.closePath(); 
context.restore();
}



function onMouseDown(e) {
//console.log('onMouseDown ' , e);
detectElement(e);
}
function onMouseMove(e) {
if(isMouseDownOn === 'scrollY') {
var posY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
scrollY = Math.min( (height-navButtonSize*2-scrollThumbHeight), Math.max(posY, 0) ) ;
origin.y = (scrollY/(height-navButtonSize*2-scrollThumbHeight))*maxHeight;

animateEverything();
}
}
function onMouseUp(e) {
//console.log('onMouseUp ' , e);
isMouseDownOn = '';

}

function drawOrigin () {
context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.font = "18px Arial";
context.fillText("Origin X:"+origin.x, 10, 30);
context.fillText("Origin Y:"+origin.y, 10, 50);
context.closePath(); 
context.restore();
}


function detectElement(e) {
isMouseDownOn = '';
var posX = e.pageX- canvas.offsetLeft;
var posY = e.pageY- canvas.offsetTop;
var currentThumbPos = scrollY+navButtonSize;

if(posX >= width-scrollBarWidth && (posY >= currentThumbPos && posY <= currentThumbPos+scrollThumbHeight) ) {
isMouseDownOn = 'scrollY';
}
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort... If you check previous answer - it was exactly what was required.  Your goodself, however, provided and great solution for a custom-made scrollbar, which is great... perhaps there is a way to detach your solution from this question and either add to the similar question or create a new question to cover your solution.